# Does mysqli class in PHP protect 100% against sql injections?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, sql-injection

I've seen lots of articles and questions about mysqli, and all of them claim that it protects against sql injections. But is it fool proof, or is there still some way to get around it. I'm not interested in cross site scripting or phishing attacks, only sql injections.

What I should have said to begin with is that I am using prepared statements. That is what I meant with mysqli. If I use prepared statements without any string concatenation, then is it foolproof?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

> But is it fool proof, or is there still some way to get around it.

No, you have to know what you're doing. If you use bound parameters (A feature that MySqli comes with), you are completely safe from injection type attacks *from this attack vector*. This doesn't prevent you - the programmer - from embedding strings directly, and thereby enabling injection attacks. You have to use the feature as intended.

#### Re: Edit

> What I should have said to begin with is that I am using prepared statements. That is what I meant with mysqli. If I use prepared statements without any string concatenation, then is it foolproof?

Foolproof is still such a dangerous word. But you are safe from injection attacks for the variables that are bound through prepared statements. This is because bound parameters are transmitted separately from the SQL query. With the "traditional" embed-string approach, the database server needs to parse the input and there are lots of edge cases in that (Charsets etc.). When the data and the query are sent separate, there is no actual parsing going on (At least not parsing of the variable data).

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't protect from sql injections any better than the old mysql module, just makes doing it easier for the developer, who can now use prepared statements instead of calling mysql_real_escape_string.